# Change python path for a specific python install

Tags: python, linux, unix, python-3.x, pythonpath

I have a full python installation with files in `/usr/local/`, but also have one that I compiled from source sitting in `~/python_dist`. If I look at `sys.path` on each interpreter I see that they indeed import from different libraries.

Currently I can run `$ PYTHONPATH=~/other_py_libs ~/python_dist/bin/python` to invoke the custom interpreter with some other modules available in the path. However, I don't want permanently change the global `PYTHONPATH` variable.

How can I permanently change the python path for only one specific python install?

Comment: you have tried virtualenv

Comment: Why can't you simply write a shell script to change PYTHONPATH when you need it. simply script it to remove one python directory from PYTHONPATH and add the desired one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (manage with [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)). With virtual environments you can set up different, isolated python environments (kind of like little python playgrounds). Switching between them (with the help of virtualenvwrapper) is as easy as typing `workon envname`. You don't have to worry about switching the PYTHONPATH around, and you can direct scripts to use a specific environment simply by running them with the python install in that environment, e.g. using `#! /home/myname/.virtualenvs/envname/bin python`.